# Is there a way to auto detect an email client's language settings and translate at that moment?

Tags: html-email, email-client, language-translation

I have lots of emails of my users that I am sending email to, but I don't know their language preference.  Is there a way that I can code my email so that it can detect the language preference when a user opens the email, and it will pull the text from a set of translations that I have already made?

I currently send emails in English, but I know that I have users from S. America and Europe.  But, all of these emails are .com domains.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to detect this in your email code.  Even if there was, there would likely be problems:

- The user may not have their client set to their preferred language.  This is very common with people who :

  1. Are comfortable in many languages, including the default language of the client.
  2. Are unwilling or don't know how to set a preferred language.
  3. Are using a basic client which only offers one or two languages.
  4. People who are learning other languages and change their language settings for learning purposes.
- The preferred language may not be the one they use (shared computers) which chances an unreadable email.

---

Instead, you could provide links in your emails to prepared translations, or an automated translator which translates your emails.